# How Android Lite Apps Works?

Tags: android, mobile-application

Yesterday, I was browsing Twitter via Google Chrome for Android. Suddenly A pop-up notification popped up asking me if I want to install a lite version of Twitter. I touched yes and then the lite version of the twitter has added to my home screen. And the same thing happens when I try to add some websites like Instagram and so on 'Add to my home screen' via chrome, they behave like a normal application. How does it work? And if I want to make my own website's lite apps, what will be the process for that?

[Two apps I am using here, twitter lite and workout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSsVg.jpg)

Comment: It's a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

It is Progressive Web app. (As Mike.M told)

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Reliable: It using Service Worker to caching resources, so very reliable. 
Engaging: With Push, Homepage Shortcut, and Full screen features, you can get more customer retention.